# SugarCRM custom field

Tags: java, rest, api, sugarcrm

I'am writing a software for the data-synchronization of a custom software and sugarCRM. Therefore I need an updateOrCreate() function. My Problem is, that the custom software uses other uuid´s than sugarCRM so i can´t look for the uuid to check on update or create.So I want to save the custom-uuid in a custom field of sugarCRM. 
But i have no idea how to do that over the REST-API of sugarCRM.
By the way I wrote a java-application.

Thank you for help!

Comment: What's your Sugar Version/Flavor? (check `/sugar_version.json` if not sure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there is no update-or-create API (see `https://your-sugarsite/rest/v10/help`), howewer if you just want to use the API (rather than customize it) you could sync data like this:

**1)** Fetch all ids of records that have a custom uuid by using the `POST /rest/v10/<module>/filter` endpoint and a payload similar to:

```
{
    offset: 0,
    max_num: 1000,
    fields: ["id", "custom_uuid_c"],
    filter: [{"custom_uuid_c": {"$not_empty": ""}}],
    ]
}
```

or if you just need a specific custom uuid at a time:

```
{
    offset: 0,
    max_num: 1000,
    fields: ["id"],
    filter: [{"custom_uuid_c": {"$equals": "example-custom-uuid"}}],
    ]
}
```

The response will look something like this:

```
{
    next_offset: -1,
    records: [
        {"id": "example-sugar-uuid", "custom_uuid_c": "example-custom-uuid"},
        ...
    ],
}
```

*Notes:*

- Make sure to evaluate `next_offset` as even with a high `max_num` you may not get all records at once because of server limits. As long as `next_offset` isn't `-1` you should use its value as `offset` in a new request to get the remaining records.
- You can supply all field names you need to sync in the `fields` array, so that you get that information early and can check whether or not an update is required at all (maybe data is still up-to-date?)
- Sugar also always include certain fields in the response, no matter if they were requested or not. (E.g. `id` and `date_modified`). I did not include them all in the response snippets for the sake of simplicity.

**2)**

Based on the information received in the previous step you know which sugar ID belongs to which custom UUID and you can detect/prepare data for updates.

If you need to sync all and retrieve the complete list first, I suggest you create a lookup table custom-uuid => sugar-id, so that you do not have to loop through the data array and compare fields when looking for a specific number.
Don't forget to consider the possibility of a custom-uuid being present in one than more Sugar-record at a time, unless you enforce them being unique on the server/database side.

**3)**

Now that you have all the information you need you can update and create records as needed:

- Update existing record: `PUT /rest/v10/<module>/<record_id>`
- Create missing record: `POST /rest/v10/<module>`

If want to send a lot of creates and/or updates in a single request, have a look at the `POST /rest/v10/bulk` API - if your version of Sugar has it.

*Final notes:*

- The filter operators definition on `/rest/v10/help` seems incomplete, for more info you can check [the filter docs](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_8.0/Architecture/Filters/#Operators)